# How to redirect after successful login setting default_target_path on all firewalls using FOSUserBundle and SonataAdminBundle in Symfony2 Security

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, symfony-security

This is my security firewall configuration:

```
firewalls:
    # Disabling the security for the web debug toolbar, the profiler and Assetic.
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
    qis:
        pattern:            /qis(.*)
        context:            user
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /login
            check_path:     /qis/login_check
        logout:
            path:           /qis/logout
        anonymous:          false

    # This firewall is used to handle the public login area
    # This part is handled by the FOS User Bundle
    main:
        pattern:             .*
        context:             user
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /login
            use_forward:    true
            default_target_path: /qis
            #always_use_default_target_path: false
            check_path:     /login_check
            failure_path:   null
        logout:
            path:           /logout
        anonymous:          true

        # Session liftime
        remember_me:
            key: '%secret%'
            lifetime: 28800

        # Sonata User Impersonating
        switch_user: true
```

Full config: [security.yml](https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/9de56b109588a30401c2)

These are the use cases that work as expected:

1. When accessing the login page /login directly the user is correctely redirected to the default_target_path qis/.
2. When accessing a page e.g. /contract user is correctely redirected back to this requested page.

I would like to achieve the same behaviour mentioned in **2** with the **qis** firewall.

BUT:

**When accessing via qis route e.g. http://localhost:8000/qis/contract/list it is not redirected to the same link but again default_target_path qis/.**

What are the required settings on the **qis** firewall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this configuration :

```
 admin:
        pattern:      /qis(.*)
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     sonata_user_admin_security_login
            use_forward:    true
            use_referer: true
            check_path:     sonata_user_admin_security_check
            failure_path:   null
        logout:
            path:           sonata_user_admin_security_logout
        anonymous:    true
```

You need to set anonymous to true to allows user to authenficate. The login page must have a public access.

Comment: Thanks @Hajri Aymen, the anonymous option was the main problem. Now my use_forward made sense too. +1 for the sonata_* placeholders. Havn't seen them in the docs those days.